# root.destroy () usage in tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

When i click cancel button in tkinter gui it exits calling root.destroy() .My doubt is root.destroy() will only exits the window or it will first destroy all the local and global variables initialized and destroy all the widgets.

Answer (score 0):

It destroys the root window and all other widgets (since they are descendants of the root window), and then `mainloop()` will exit. It won't destroy any non-tkinter variables or objects that you have created. However, for most tkinter apps the application will then exit and all variables will of course be destroyed since `mainloop()` is typically the last line of code in the file.